# How to return an integer value as a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What would be the best way to return an integer value as a string in MySQL? For example:

```
>select id from table;
>1
```

but return it as string rather than integer? There are references to cast as causing major headaches with different values even for integer to string conversion.

Comment: What would be unsafe?

Comment: I see online that a lot of people don't reccomend using cast() as it has unexpected results. Perhaps in such a trivial one as this is fine.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I don't see why `CAST(id)` is unsafe. You can also use `CONCAT(id)`, but there's really no difference.

Comment: Please reference such problems. That would be a severe bug indeed. I've never encountered any problem with cast so far.

Comment: ok, probably not a problem then. I'll just use concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way is to use `cast()`.  Do you have an issue with that?

```
select cast(id as varchar(255))
from table;
```

If there are issues with `cast()` with integers, I am not familiar with them, as long as the destination type is long enough to hold the value.  You can always use `format()` instead.

Perhaps you are thinking of issues when converting floating point numbers to a string.  Then you have a problem that 1.1 might end up looking like 1.09999999997 or whatever.  That is an issue with inexact floating point representations, not integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast to VARCHAR but only to CHAR so try this :

```
select cast(id as char(10))
from table;
```